# Add md5 hash to URL in htaccess to prevent caching

Tags: .htaccess

I have a joomla site and I am using cloudflare caching. The problem with cloudflare is that it cached joomla administrator pages as well. This has cause a lot of inconvenience when maintaining the site. I have used up all my cloudflare page rules for other usage so looking of an alternative solution.

One thing I know is whenever the URL parameter changes, Cloudflare will not deliver cached page. So the idea is to append auto generated md5 hash to all requesting url that has administrator word in them.

Eg.

```
http://mysite/administrator/index.php
will append md5 and become 
http://mysite/administrator/index.php?md5=59b466fd93164953e56bdd1358dc0044
```

and

```
http://mysite/administrator/index.php?foo=1 
will append md5 and become 
http://mysite/administrator/index.php?foo=1&md5=59b466fd93164953e56bdd1358dc0044
```

I am not sure how to do this. I have the below but its not working and I have very little knowledge of regex and htaccess codes.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %^/administrator(/[\w-]*)?$% [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ https://mysite%{REQUEST_URI}&mci=$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Can anyone please advice? Thanks

Comment: From url `http://mysite/administrator/index.php?foo=1&md5=59b466fd93164953e56bdd1358dc0044` to which url you want to redirect?

Comment: No, Im not trying to redirect. It is the same URL just with md5 hash attached to the it...
The original is http://mysite/administrator/index.php?foo=1 

I want it to become 

http://mysite/administrator/index.php?foo=1&md5=59b466fd93164953e56bdd1358dc0044

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to add md5 values into it. htaccess can't dynamically generate and add values to urls.

Comment: Would this even work? If cloudflare delivers an already cached version when I request `/administrator/index.php` – is your web server even coming into play then, so that it could issue any such redirect?

Comment: @user Might be worth asking on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange; maybe someone there has experienced a similar thing and can offer some advice that worked for them.  (more generally, if you are a Joomla user, it is a good idea to join/search JSE for support/research)